# Session gets updated when the linked variable is updated

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have seen many posts here regarding storing Lists in Sessions and then retrieving them. Most of the answers follow this technique:

```
if(Session["Strings"]==null)
{
      //Create List
      List<string> strings = new List<string>();
      ...
      Session["Strings"] = strings;
}
else
      strings =   Session["Strings"] as List<string>

//Add item to list
strings.Add("asdf");
```

I have tried this but as soon as I update the list, the session variable is updated also and on postback I get the updated value in the Session. Is this the expected behavior? How do to use this so that the session is not updated? I have even tried to set the 'strings' variable to null after use but the session still has the added item on each postback.

Maybe i can add some concrete code to explain.

Lets say I have a button click event on my page:

```
     protected void GoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    List<string> a;
    if(Session["data"] == null)
    {
        a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("abc");
        a.Add("def");
        a.Add("ghi");

        Session["data"] = a;
    }
    else
    {
        a = (Session["data"] as List<string>);
    }
    a.Add("jkl");
    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        lblTest.Text += s + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Each time I click the button, I should expect 'a' to contain only 4 values as I am fetching it from the Session and it is a local variable. But actually each time I click it, the value 'jkl' is added so number of values keep increasing. I dont want that to happen. I hope I am more clearer.

Comment: Is this using In-Proc Session or Out-Proc? I wonder if this will happen for the Out-Proc?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ViewState is the one you search for. Try to keep them on ViewState for keep this variables inside the page. This is the code that you can use for that:

```
const string _cListWStringsName = "cListWStrings_cnst";

public List<string> cListWStrings
{
    set
    {
        ViewState[_cListWStringsName] = value;
    }
    get
    {
        if (ViewState[_cListWStringsName] is List<string>)
        {
            return (List<string>)ViewState[_cListWStringsName];
        }
        else
        {
            var NewOne = new List<string>();

            ViewState[_cListWStringsName] = NewOne;

            return NewOne;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is similar to the one I posted except you are using a ViewState and defining a property. I have tried using the ViewState as well - that gets updated also as soon the variable 'strings' is updated. I think this has something to do with 'strings' being a ref type. It works alright when I use a simple integer.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click the button, four values are added "abc", "def", "ghi" and "jkl". And on each consecutive clicks "jkl" is added because a.Add("jkl") lies outside the if clause. You need to move it inside the if clause, here it is:

```
 protected void GoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    List<string> a;
    if(Session["data"] == null)
    {
        a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("abc");
        a.Add("def");
        a.Add("ghi");
        a.Add("jkl");//Move here
        Session["data"] = a;
    }
    else
    {
        a = (Session["data"] as List<string>);
    }

    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        lblTest.Text += s + "<br />";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**Session holds a reference to the List and so does a. Both are referencing the same list, so if you make change in a or in session, the referenced list will get changed. Remember, Session is storing the reference and not the value. Now, why does "ijk" keeps on adding? Because the list never goes out of scope(even after your method finishes executing), it remains there as long as does the Session, so when your code adds "ijk" to "a" its actually adding the value to the list. So it keeps adding the value "ijk" to the list which Session is referencing.

Comment: No, that defeats the purpose. I could easily have the initializing code in the Page_Load and adding an item code in the button click. it should work in both cases. The Session should not update when the variable is updated

Comment: Please, have a look at the updated answer. I am pretty much sure, it will clear your doubt and solve your problem.

Comment: Mark your question answered if I helped you. Thanks.